# How to use google credentials to create a user in feathers js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, feathersjs

how do I use google credentials to decode and get the data I need and use it to register a user?
Im using this component library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google which gives me the google credentials

https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/google.html#application-client-and-secret
this shows only how to setup but doesnt show how to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use any JWT decoder to get user info from credentials key
like https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode or any package, or any logic you like to decode

Comment: So how do i setup feathers js so that I can get an endpoint to send the credentials and create a user based on it? do i have to manually make them or does feathersjs already has built it functions for it?